# invalid JavaScript signature still calls correct API

Tags: javascript, api, webkit, v8, sfx

**why does this work ?**

```
<html>
<body id = "body">
<div id="para">hello world, invalid js API signature doesn't throw error !!!</div>
<script>
var temp = document.getSelection("parameter");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

getSelection() does not take any parameter as per standard signature.
I have tested this and it does not throw any error on JS console either.

Comment: I've just tested on a home made function ... looks like javascript doesn't throw an error on a parameter being passed where it isn't needed or defined in the function signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't complain if you call a function with the wrong number of arguments. If there are fewer arguments passed than declared, the extra parameters have the value `undefined`. If there are more, they are simply ignored. This is a feature and not a bug!

Inside the JavaScript function you have access to the `arguments` value which is an array-like structure holding all the arguments passed to it. If you wanted you could define all your functions to take 0 parameters and use `arguments[0]`, `arguments[1]`, etc instead of the named parameters you previously had (though i don't see why one would do that) and the functions would still work exactly the same.

The benefits of having this `arguments` structure and no limits on how many arguments you call a function with allows you to do very powerfull things, like the bind polyfill found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Answer (score 1):

If I have the following JavaScript function

```
function foo(first, last){
    return "from Foo";
}
```

JavaScript will execute and will return for all of the following

```
foo();
foo(2);
foo("abc");
foo("abc", 3, 5);
```

If you want to deal with all the passed parameter. you can get those from "arguments". 
[MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments)